# How to access the value from previous aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to calculate some statistics using elastic index documents. 
How to acces the values calculated in previous steps?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ave_y_true": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "y_true"
          }
        },
        "grades_stats": {
          "extended_stats": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['y_true'].value - params.correction",
              "lang": "painless",
              "params": {
                "correction": 2.875
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The value "2.875" should actually be the value of average of the bucket that I have already calculated. ave_y_true field in this case.